# ¿Cómo devolver determinado valor o booleano si se encuentra en el string?

Tags: javascript, array, string, condiciones, bucles

estoy haciendo un preparatorio para ingresar a un BootCamp. Este ejercicio es de prueba y me gustaría saber en que estoy mal.

```
function encontrarLaPalabra(string) {
  // Escribir una funcion que reciba un string (string) y retorne true si encuentra la palabra "henry" adentro.
  // si no, retorna false.
  // Ej:
  // encontrarLaBomba('bienvenidos a henry') => true;
  // encontrarLaBomba('hola que tal, como va?!') => false;

  // Tu código:
  for(var i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
  if(string.length === "henry") {
    return true;
   }
  }
  return false;
}
```

No se si para devolver determinada string es diferente a si uno devuelve determinado número dentro del array o string, pero agradecería cualquier correción o retroalimentación, gracias.

Answer (score 1):

básicamente estás mal en la comparación.

`string.length` es un valor entero que indica la longitud de la cadena `string`, mientras `"henry"` es una cadena, al utilizar triple igual como comparador `===`, le indicas que ambos lados deben ser del mismo tipo, y el mismo valor. Por lo que básicamente falla.

Lo segundo, debes obtener una subcadena de la longitud de `"henry"`, con la cual debes de comparar `"henry"`, esto con la función `substr`, que recibe como primer parametro la posición inicial, y el segundo parametro la longitud de la nueva cadena.

```
  for(var i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
  if(string.substr(i, 5) === "henry") {
    return true;
   }
  }
  return false;
```

Comment: Hola amigo.¿ Para la palabra debo de siempre hacer un substr y establecer el length de la string en cuestión que quiera encontrar? ¿Para numero sería string.integer(i, integer)?

Comment: Si, si buscas hola, debes obtener un substring de longitud 4, que es probable que sea igual al hola que buscas

Comment: @LuisDanielArciniegasBarco no, el método que propones: `string.integer(i, integer)` no tiene sentido y no existe en el Objeto [`String`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String) de Javascript. Saludos

Comment: Cierto @MauricioContreras, es el metodo `String.substr(index, length)`, donde index indica la posición inicial, y length es la cantidad de caracteres a obteber

Comment: Por ciertto @HammerffallBK en tu código se puede optimizar un par de cosas: *si el string recibido tiene menor tamaño que el buscado, puedes devolver directamente `false`.* Por otro lado: *no hace falta iterar desde `0` hasta `string.length`, basta con iterar desde `0` hasta el carácter donde ya no exista un `substring` de tamaño 5*. Saludos

Answer (score 1):

Otra forma es usar directamente el método [`includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/includes) del tipo `String`, el cual devuelve un valor booleano dependiendo si la cadena objetivo contiene el argumento de cadena pasado a la función.

Por ejemplo:

```js
function encontrarLaPalabra(cadena) {
  // Escribir una funcion que reciba un string (string) y retorne true si encuentra la palabra "henry" adentro.
  // si no, retorna false.
  // Ej:
  // encontrarLaBomba('bienvenidos a henry') => true;
  // encontrarLaBomba('hola que tal, como va?!') => false;

  // Tu código:
  return cadena.includes("henry");
}

const cadenas = [
  "Henry no está aquí",
  "Sin embargo, henry sí que está aquí",
  "bienvenidos a henry",
  "hola que tal, como va?!"
];

cadenas.forEach(cadena => {
  console.log(encontrarLaPalabra(cadena));
});
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

Espero que esto te ayude a resolver el problema.